# Change apt-get install path to 2nd hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, apt, partition, hard-disk, xubuntu

I am new to Linux. I've installed Xubuntu instead of Windows 10 and I am happy with it but I am really curious if I can change the path of applications installed via apt-get install (or by any other ways for installing applications, like .deb packages). I currently have two hard drives - 1) 128GB SSD (currently about 100GB free), which is the booting and system folder and 2) 1TB HDD where is the /home/ direcotry. I really wan't to be able to store my applications on the HDD instead of the SSD, because I am scared that I will run out of space soon (f.e. I want to play World of Warcraft which is about 80GB's so I dont want to have it on disk where is about 100GB of free space). Is there any possible solution? I will be really happy for any help, Thanks!

Comment: I believe you can install WoW where you want it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your going to be using Steam to install your games you can select where the games library is stored.  And if your going to use wine to install WOW wine uses a folder in your home directory to store games so either way you should be good.

Hope this helps,
Jason C.